# One label for multiple series

Tags: highcharts

I need to make one label responsible for multiple series data.
As shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HHqGN/ , I have two series:

**test(bid)** and **test(ask)** and two labels responsible for each of them.

What I need is one label named test instead of these two to toggle both serie 1 and serie 2 at the same time

Sample code from fiddle:

```
$(function() {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            enabled : false
        },

        legend : {
            enabled : true
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'test(bid)',
            data : [[1152057600000,57.00]
        }, {
            name : 'test(ask)',
            data : [[1152057600000,58.00]
        }]
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable displaying second serie in legend, by [showInLegend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.showInLegend) parameter and then use [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) to show/hide both series

http://jsfiddle.net/HHqGN/1/

```
legendItemClick:function(){

                    $.each(this.chart.series,function(i,serie){
                        if(serie.visible)
                            serie.hide();
                        else
                            serie.show();
                    });

                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But what if I would like to have two different pair of series? Say, **usd(bid)** and **usd(ask)** for one label - **usd** and **eur(bid)** and **eur(ask)** for second label - **eur**

Comment: when you need to modify legendItemCLick and recognise which series shoudl be hidden which not. I.e by adding id for each serie.

Comment: How should I add an id for the serie?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for linked series have a look at the [`linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.linkedTo) parameter of a series. As per definition:

> `linkedTo: StringSince 3.0`
>
> The `id` of another series to link to. Additionally, the value can be
>   `":previous"` to link to the previous series. When two series are
>   linked, only the first one appears in the legend. Toggling the
>   visibility of this also toggles the linked series.

Source: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts